# Moving files to archive directory using apache camel ftp component

Tags: spring, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have few files stored in a database, these files were fetched from a FTP server and processed.

I am trying to move these files to archive directory on FTP server and to do that I am using `producerTemplate`.

This is what I have done so far.

```java
try {
    DefaultCamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
    template.request("ftp://xxxxx/include=fileFromDb.xml&move=archive/fileFromDb.xml", outExchange -> {
        String body = outExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);                    
    });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // update the status in database to indicate archive failed
}
```

But this is failing with following error and can't get this resolved.

```
WARN  o.a.c.c.f.remote.RemoteFileProducer - Writing file failed with: Cannot write null body to file: archive/ID-192-168-1-113-tpgi-com-au-1627667653835-1-2
```

I have tried implementing solutions from other answers but they didn't worked for either.

If I write a custom route like below, it works fine but because I need perform post move actions I prefere using producer template.

```java
from("ftp://xxxxx/include=fileFromDb.xml&move=archive/fileFromDb.xml")
    .log("file moved successfully").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I write a custom route like below, it works fine but because I need perform post move actions I prefere using producer template.

You could use onCompletion to call another route to handle the post move actions.

```java
String sftpURI = "sftp:localhost:2222/upload" +
"?username="+username+"&password="+password
+ "&move=done";

String sftpPostMoveURI = "sftp:localhost:2222/upload/done" +
"?username="+username+"&password="+password
+ "&fileName=${headers.CamelFileName}";

from(sftpURI)
    .routeId("ReadFileUsingSFTPRoute")
    .onCompletion().onCompleteOnly()
        .setBody().constant("")
        .to("direct:postMoveActions")
    .end()
    .log("file ${headers.CamelFileName} moved");

from("direct:postMoveActions")
    .routeId("PostMoveActionsRoute")
    .log("doing post move actions!")
    .pollEnrich().simple(sftpPostMoveURI).timeout(5000)
    .log("File: ${body}");
```